# return only specified number of words

Tags: php, nl2br

I have some HTML tagged text, which I want to output only 40 words of.

e.g.

```
<strong>This is an article </strong> containing 150 words with <a href="">HTML
</a>tags and I want to output only first 40 words. How to do this?
```

I am using nl2br right now, because it has EOLs. `explode()` and `str_word_count` take into account only regular words.

Comment: any reason you have used a "nl2br" word in your question?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: Click "Improve" and you can edit it.

Comment: this stupid engine won't let me. it will leave it for someone else to review

Comment: Do you need to preserve the formatting, or just output the plain text?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel I don't really know. Thanks for revision :-)

Comment: anyhow, I'd welcome an answer more :-)

Comment: you can use a search. this question has been asked 1000 times already

Comment: @Leigh I need to preserve the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some googling I found what I was looking for (at this forum http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/10821.htm)

The function cuts specified number of characters from the string and then adds characters up to next space (to prevent cutting in the middle of a word).

```
function elliStr($string,$noChars) { 
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) { 
    $result = ($noChars+$i >= strlen($string) ? $string : ($string{$noChars+$i} == " " ? substr($string,0,$noChars+$i) : ""));
    if ( $result != "" ) {
        return nl2br($result);
        } 
    }
}
```